# How should I go about creating intellisense for my own javascript libraries in VS?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do to obtain javascript intellisense for my own js library in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452760/what-should-i-do-to-obtain-javascript-intellisense-for-my-own-js-library-in-visu)

Is there a how-to on the subject of creating intellisense for your own javascript libraries and classes in Visual Studio?

And is there a way to get it to work across multiple files? What are the rules for this? Does it have to be in the same project? The best solution would be to just include the javascript file in my Master, and then have my "local" javascript files be able to "read" the intellisense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good How to in MSDN you can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx) and also there is a walkthrough example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385674.aspx)

Comment: I can only get it to work within that one particular javascript file. See my edit above...

Comment: As far as I know; if you want to make it work across multiple files all files have to be in the same project and in each file you want to use the intellisense you need to add this `/// <reference path="yourJS.js" />`. like if you want to refer to object from file1.js in file2.js you will add `/// <reference path="file1.js" />` as the first line in file2.js

Comment: Works like a charm! One last thing, though: Is it possible to have line breaks in the intellisense comments? Some of the `<param>`'s have fairly long text, and I'd like to break it up...