# What should I do to obtain javascript intellisense for my own js library in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I have multiple javascript files and they have their own functions. If I make reference one of them to inside any of them, it doesnt see its functions if the function is not prototype. What is logic inside the Intellisense ?

I want to use Splash function with Intellisense feature below, how can I do that ?

```
//My.js
/// <reference path="Test.js" />
```

.

```
//Test.js
NameSpace.prototype.UI = new function () {

    this.Splash = function (value) {
        try {
            if (value == 1) {
                $('#splash').css('height', $(document).height());
                $('#splashContent').css('top', $(window).height() / 2);
                $('#splash').fadeIn();
                $('#splashContent').fadeIn();
                setTimeout("SF.UI.Splash(0)", 3000);
            }
            else if (value == 0) {
                $('#splash').fadeOut(1000);
                $('#splashContent').fadeOut(1000);
            }
            else if (value == 3) {
                $('#splash').css('height', $(document).height());
                $('#splashContent').css('top', $(window).height() / 2);
                $('#splash').fadeIn();
                $('#splashContent').fadeIn();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            Splash(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so, does it not work if you have a reference on the page? according to this it should: http://blog.turlov.com/2010/05/leveraging-visual-studio-javascript.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS Intellisense is flaky at best. Despite all those articles, in my experience, it doesn't work as advertised. I would suggest:

- Make sure all your JS files are in the same project (making ti work across projects is even trickier).
- Make sure `/// <reference path="Test.js" />` is the very first line in JS.
- Make sure there are no errors in the `Test.js` file (run JSLint on it to be sure) or use the vsdoc approach.
- Look at the `Output` tool window to see if it contains any errors related to updating intellisense. This will help you troubleshoot and remove errors in your referenced JS file.

Alternative to create a `Test-vsdoc.js` file (this way, even if your main JS file has errors, it would not cause intellisense to fail) :

```
//Test-vsdoc.js
NameSpace.prototype.UI = new function () {

    this.Splash = function (value) {
    /// <summary>This is my function summary</summary>
    }
}
```

VS would automatically include it next time you restart the IDE (or try a force update <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that is the actual contents of your js file, including the `//My.js` comment, then that is your problem right there.

`/// <reference` comments must be at the very top of the file, before any other content, otherwise they will not work.

Side note, did you know there is a code snippet for that reference?  its `ref`, then <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>.  Also you can drag / drop a file and get the comment.

Once you have your references done, you can force VS2010 to refresh your js comments by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> while editing the .js file